# Trivial question about product measures on the real line

Tags: probability

Let $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} $. Denote by $\mathscr{B}^2$ the borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathscr{B}$ the borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}$. I know this question may seem trivial, but how can I justify that in fact $\mathscr{B}^2 = \mathscr{B} \otimes \mathscr{B}$ ( the smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathscr{B} \times \mathscr{B} $ )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more topology than measure theory. Essentially it's because the natural metric on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ (with open rectangles as a basis), is equivalent to the  euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with basis of open balls). Since $\mathscr{B}^2$ is generated by open balls, and $\mathscr{B}\times\mathscr{B}$ is generated by products of open intervals (rectangles), they are the same.